# (VBA EXCEL) IF function

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to make my code delete some rows based on the number inputed on my `textbox2`. First it will delete some heading cells, and then it will delete more cells.

The problem is on the heading cells part, my code is ignoring the entire `if` statement. I don't know why. Here it is:

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

'\/ DSE

If Range("A5").Value <> "1" Then
GoTo PortalDSI
End If
MsgBox ("DSE")
T = 337
Y = TextBox2.Value



If Y < 1 Then
MsgBox ("Ué?")
End
ElseIf Y < 40 And Y > 0 Then
    Rows("302:305").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Rows("259:262").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Rows("216:219").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Rows("173:176").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Rows("130:133").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Rows("87:90").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Rows("44:47").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    s = 28
    D = 5
ElseIf Y < 79 And Y > 39 Then
    Rows("302:305").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Rows("259:262").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Rows("216:219").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Rows("173:176").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Rows("130:133").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Rows("87:90").Delete Shift:=xlUp
     s = 24
     D = 9
ElseIf Y < 118 And Y > 78 Then
    Rows("302:305").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Rows("259:262").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Rows("216:219").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Rows("173:176").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Rows("130:133").Delete Shift:=xlUp
     s = 20
     D = 13
ElseIf Y < 157 And Y > 117 Then
    Rows("302:305").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Rows("259:262").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Rows("216:219").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Rows("173:176").Delete Shift:=xlUp
     s = 16
     D = 17
ElseIf Y < 196 And Y > 156 Then
    Rows("302:305").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Rows("259:262").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Rows("216:219").Delete Shift:=xlUp
     s = 12
     D = 21
ElseIf Y < 235 And Y > 195 Then
    Rows("302:305").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Rows("259:262").Delete Shift:=xlUp
     s = 8
     D = 25
ElseIf Y < 274 And Y > 234 Then
    Rows("302:305").Delete Shift:=xlUp
     s = 4
     D = 29
ElseIf Y > 274 And Y < 305 Then
s = 4
D = 29
ElseIf Y > 305 Then
MsgBox ("Na mão")
End
End If

'B is fixed (:

Z = T - Y
A = Y + D
B = T - s

Rows(A & ":" & B).Delete Shift:=x1down

End

' DSE /\

PortalDSI:
MsgBox ("DSI")

Y = TextBox2.Value

If Y < 1 Then
MsgBox ("Como Assim?")
End
End If

If Y = 1 Then

Rows("9:9").Delete Shift:=x1down
End If
If Y > 2 Then

Dim I
For I = 1 To Y - 2
Rows("9:9").Insert Shift:=x1down
Next I
Else
End
End If

T = Y - 1
Range("A8").Value = 1
Range("A9").Select
Dim J
For J = 1 To T
activecell.Offset(-1, 0).Select
v = Selection.Value
activecell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Selection.Value = v + 1
activecell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Next J

Range("B9").Select
Dim O
For O = 1 To T
activecell.Value = "1 CX"
activecell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Next O

Range("D8").Select
Unload Me

End Sub
```

I am really lost here, I tried everything I could find. Please, help me.

Comment: You may need to select all the rows at once that you want deleted. Say you wanted to delete Rows 1 and Rows 3, if you delete rows 1 first, row 3 now becomes, row 2, because you have shifted cells up, But if you select Row1 and row 3 at  once, then delete, you will have a successful deletion(whew!). Select Many rows at once by Pressing the Ctrl & selecting the rows.

Comment: What makes you think it is ignoring this code?  As a side note, the way you have this structured, if Y<40, then ALL of the IF statements will be executed.  You might was to use IF...ELSEIF...ELSEIF...END IF structure.

Comment: Please specify the issue clearly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just cleaned it a little, but you'll have to try it, I'm not too sure it works as you wanted it:

```
If ActiveWorkbook.ActiveWorksheet.Range("A5").Value <> "1" Then
   GoTo PortalDSI
End If

MsgBox ("DSE")
T = 305
Y = TextBox2.Value

With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    If Y < 1 Then
        MsgBox ("Ué?")
    ElseIf Y < 40 And Y > 0 Then
        .Rows("302:305").Delete Shift:=xlUp
        .Rows("259:262").Delete Shift:=xlUp
        .Rows("216:219").Delete Shift:=xlUp
        .Rows("173:176").Delete Shift:=xlUp
        .Rows("130:133").Delete Shift:=xlUp
        .Rows("87:90").Delete Shift:=xlUp
        .Rows("44:47").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    ElseIf Y < 79 And Y > 39 Then
        .Rows("302:305").Delete Shift:=xlUp
        .Rows("259:262").Delete Shift:=xlUp
        .Rows("216:219").Delete Shift:=xlUp
        .Rows("173:176").Delete Shift:=xlUp
        .Rows("130:133").Delete Shift:=xlUp
        .Rows("87:90").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    ElseIf Y < 118 And Y > 78 Then
        .Rows("302:305").Delete Shift:=xlUp
        .Rows("259:262").Delete Shift:=xlUp
        .Rows("216:219").Delete Shift:=xlUp
        .Rows("173:176").Delete Shift:=xlUp
        .Rows("130:133").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    ElseIf Y < 157 And Y > 117 Then
        .Rows("302:305").Delete Shift:=xlUp
        .Rows("259:262").Delete Shift:=xlUp
        .Rows("216:219").Delete Shift:=xlUp
        .Rows("173:176").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    ElseIf Y < 196 And Y > 156 Then
        .Rows("302:305").Delete Shift:=xlUp
        .Rows("259:262").Delete Shift:=xlUp
        .Rows("216:219").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    ElseIf Y < 235 And Y > 195 Then
        .Rows("302:305").Delete Shift:=xlUp
        .Rows("259:262").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    ElseIf Y < 274 And Y > 234 Then
        .Rows("302:305").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    End If
End With

Z = T - Y
A = Y + 4
B = T + 4

ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Rows(A & ":" & B).Delete Shift:=x1down

End
```

For the future try to avoid selecting and activating. The code can still be run even if the range is not selected.

*** EDIT ***

Be more specific with the workbooks and sheets you're working on. Instead of ActiveSheet I would work with "ActivWorkbook.Sheets("NameOfYourSheet")" which can also be set into a variable like

```
Dim ShtXY As Worksheet
ShtXY = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("NameOfYourSheet")
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

'\/ DSE

If Range("A5").Value <> "1" Then
GoTo PortalDSI
End If
MsgBox ("DSE")
T = 305
Y = TextBox2.Value



If Y < 1 Then
MsgBox ("Ué?")


`enter code here`' else if's are doing nothing, but they are being ran.
ElseIf Y < 40 And Y > 0 Then
        Rows("302:305").Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Rows("259:262").Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Rows("216:219").Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Rows("173:176").Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Rows("130:133").Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Rows("87:90").Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Rows("44:47").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    ElseIf Y < 79 And Y > 39 Then
        Rows("302:305").Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Rows("259:262").Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Rows("216:219").Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Rows("173:176").Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Rows("130:133").Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Rows("87:90").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    ElseIf Y < 118 And Y > 78 Then
        Rows("302:305").Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Rows("259:262").Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Rows("216:219").Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Rows("173:176").Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Rows("130:133").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    ElseIf Y < 157 And Y > 117 Then
        Rows("302:305").Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Rows("259:262").Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Rows("216:219").Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Rows("173:176").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    ElseIf Y < 196 And Y > 156 Then
        Rows("302:305").Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Rows("259:262").Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Rows("216:219").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    ElseIf Y < 235 And Y > 195 Then
        Rows("302:305").Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Rows("259:262").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    ElseIf Y < 274 And Y > 234 Then
        Rows("302:305").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    End If



Z = T - Y
A = Y + 4
B = T + 4

Rows(A & ":" & B).Delete Shift:=x1down



' DSE /\


'From here on everything is fine \/


PortalDSI:
MsgBox ("DSI")

Y = TextBox2.Value

If Y < 1 Then
MsgBox ("Como Assim?")

End If

If Y = 1 Then

Rows("9:9").Delete Shift:=x1down
End If
If Y > 2 Then

Dim I
For I = 1 To Y - 2
Rows("9:9").Insert Shift:=x1down
Next I
Else

End If

T = Y - 1
Range("A8").Value = 1
Range("A9").Select
Dim J
For J = 1 To T
activecell.Offset(-1, 0).Select
v = Selection.Value
activecell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Selection.Value = v + 1
activecell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Next J

Range("B9").Select
Dim O
For O = 1 To T
activecell.Value = "1 CX"
activecell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Next O

Range("D8").Select
Unload Me

End Sub
```

As cindy said above its not getting into the **IF** conditions due the **END** command before **END IF**. Use the END command where you want to **exit** the current **SUB**

Comment: The "END" parts is fine, it is really supposed to end if my Y is < than 0, anyways, to reach the END part it has to show me a message box as you can see there, so i would know this END part is being ran. (I tried anyways, it went all throug the else ifs without doing anything)